# Restrict Approval Requirement to List Item Creation

Tags: workflow, versioning, approval-process, approval

I have set an approval requirement on my list, so that whenever an item is created, it will be in "draft mode" until it is approved by the user with the required permissions. Here is a screenshot of the settings I have :

[image]

This works, but it also sets items to "unnaproved" status after editing.

Is there a way of setting this so that only new items need approval? I am not interested in approving items which have been edited, but I can't seem to find a way of removing this feature.

I have checked in the 2013 Workflow Actions but can't find anything which affects `Approval Status`

---

**Update**

I noticed that I can see `Approval Status` if I add a Condition to the workflow :

[image]

but I can't actually change the value from here ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After removing the `Edit` workflow, I created a new one, but this time I created a `2010` workflow, and the option to update approval status is now under Actions menu.